# Matlab plot remove tickmark

Tags: matlab, plot

I have this plot and I need to remove the black short line showing the tick-marks as seen in following figure.
[image]

```
plot([0:10],[5:15])
grid minor
set(gca, 'YGrid', 'off')
set(gca, 'YMinorGrid', 'off')
set(gca, 'YTickLabel','')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a thread on [matlabcentral](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/41117) discussing this issue. You can not remove them. The trick is to set their length to zero. Add the following to your example and it should work:

```
set(gca,'TickLength',[ 0 0 ])
```